# Problemas em qualquer projeto java que crio no eclipse

Tags: eclipse

pessoal seguinte ta acontecendo uma coisa muito estranha que tipo qualquer projeto que crio no eclipse ele da vários erros e não reconhece nada nas minhas classes do java, já tentei fazer um monte de coisa removi todas as versões antigas do java que eu tinha mais não adiantou ainda continua da mesma maneira.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422727/5524514)?

Comment: eu tenho um problema nao uma solução!

Comment: Já tentou atualizar seu maven project?

Comment: Não entendi seu comentário. No link q mandei, tem uma "possível solução".

Comment: eu tenho o java 8 configurado na minha maquina onde encontro o jar dele?